# Destructuring an object in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I have this TS code, and I want to make that part to be also typed :

```
    const { data: { person, car, another } }: any = useContext(MyContext);
```

the issue here is that ES lint says:
`warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`

I have 3 interfaces created for person, car, another and I want to reuse them after the useContext.
My objective is to just share person, car, another

Any clues?

Comment: `typeof MyContext` instead of `any` comes to mind... though if `MyContext` already has a type, omitting the `: any` entirely may suffice to provide strict typing for `person`, `car`, and `another`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type annotations cannot be placed in destructuring operations, the `:` character already has a use there as a way to assign a property being destructed to a new name.

```
const { person: p2 } = { person: "Name" }
p2 === "Name" // true
```

You could replace the `any` with the type you expect from `useContext`.

```
const { data: { person, car, another } }: { data: { person: Person, car: Car, another: Another } }
  = useContext(MyContext);
```

But ideally the type of the return of `useContext` should be inferred from the parameter passed to it, when you create the context you should have a line like:

```
type ContextType = {data: {person: Person, car: Car, another: Another}}
const MyContext = createContext<ContextType>({/* default value */})
```

When you then use `useContext` the value that is returned will already have the `ContextType` and your destructuring will be typed without required any type annotations.

Comment: great! I was creating the type of the context like an "interface" and it seems that TS do not likes that for this kind of objects. I created it with "type" and now it works.

Comment: @RicardoDaniel, it should work just as well as interfaces, can't think of why it wouldn't. If this has solved your problem can you accept the answer.